# lagrange method, linear constraints and unique global maximum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier

My book in linear programming states two things that I do not understand. We are working with the lagrange method with linear constraints.:

[image]

From multivariate calculus we have that at a critical point we must have:
[image], these equations are called 17.3 in the proof below.

Now comes the part I do not understand. In the proof that follow:

**1.[GREEN LINE] What is it that makes the proof hold for linear constraints, why do they need to specify that, if the g functions were not linear wouldn't the proof still hold?**

**2.[RED SQUARE] Why do they get a unique global maximum if 17.4 holds?, I can't see how the unique part just follows?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What requires linear constraints is the proof. The assertion *the only displacements that are relevant are those that lie in the feasible set* is easily true if the constraints are linear, that is, the feasible set is a linear subspace and (17.5) just says $\xi$ is parallel to the set. If the set has some curvature (degree of constraints $>1$), then (17.5) says $\xi$ is tangent to the set at $x^*$, and it may very well happen that any displacement in that direction escapes the set. But in that setting teh result is also true, although the proof requires a more careful understanding of Hessian. This enters in fact the realm of *Calculus on manifolds,* which I guess beyond the scope here.

For the red box, suppose we have $f(y^*)>f(x^*)$. Since the constraints are linear the line $L$ joining $y^*$ to $x^*$ is contained in the feasible set, and then we can work with the restriction of $f|L$. This is a one-variable function with one local maximum and a higher value, hence it must have a local minimum $z^*\in L$ between them. At that local minimum the second derivative of the restriction is $\ge0$, and after some computation one gets $\xi^THf(z^*)\xi\ge0$ for the direction $\xi$ of $L$.