# Does convexity together with linear constraints imply Lagrange method finds an optimum on infinite-dimensional spaces?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, banach-spaces, lagrange-multiplier, frechet-derivative

As one can see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316339/lagrange-multipliers-on-banach-spaces), one can use Lagrange's method on Banach spaces.

That is, let $X$ be a banach space and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

Suppose we have another function $T$ on $X$, that imposes constraints, that is we want to optimize $f$ on the set $\{x \in U| T(x) = 0\}$, where $U$ is some open(convex?) subset of $X$.  Now assume that both $f$ and $T$ are frechet differentiable. Then a necessary condition for a minimum $x^*$ is that there exists $\lambda$ such that

$$\mathcal{L}(x^*,\lambda) = D_f(x^*) +  \lambda D_T(x^*) =0.$$

In the finite-dimensional case, if $f$ is convex and $T$ is affine, as can be seen for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222347/lagrange-method-linear-constraints-and-unique-global-maximum), then this is also a sufficient condition.

Now, does this carry over to the infinite-dimensional situation? Especifically, when $T$ is a linear operator, is

$$D_f(x^*) + \lambda T = 0 $$
a sufficient condition?